# Is it possible to create custom field control and custom edit forms for sharepoint online?

Tags: custom-form, sharepoint-online, custom-field-types

Is it possible to create custom field control and custom edit forms for sharepoint online?

Would like to do the same as explained in http://bit.ly/yoON5T but instead for sharepoint online. Point is that in sharepoint online, you're not able to write to the CONTROLTEMPLATES folder. Anyone has experience/solution?

Answer (score 2):

As of today, Developing a sandboxed solution is the only way you can upload and run custom code in SharePoint Online and Custom Field Types are not supported in a Sandboxed solutions. So it is NOT possible.

Check this white paper to understand what you can do with SharePoint online: [SharePoint Online for Office 365 Developer Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147180.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Was already afraid that it would not be possible to create Custom Field Types, pity.

Comment: yes, I hope the situation improves and they find way ways to overcome the limitations.